# Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized' error when i try to open db diagram in ASP.NET MVC Code First Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and entity framework I was following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) tutorial to create an application with code first approach, the problem is program runs perfectly but i cannot see tables created in localdb, I am getting this error (Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized') whenever I try to open tables from server explorer connection, in any connection.

I have visual studio 2013 and sql server 2014, i guess the problem is about sql server 2014 because in [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eb66b20f-7df9-46d4-9aba-a7bf31efcdb3/invalid-column-name-is-memory-optimized-when-i-try-to-create-database-diagram?forum=sqltools) website they say that "Something is not what it should be. 'is_memory_optimized' relates to a new feature in SQL 2014. I can't say what happned, but I would suggest that you install service pack 2 of SQL 2012 which was released recently. With a little luck it repairs the error." in msdn forums but none of the comments solved the problem i also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356919/invalid-column-name-is-memory-optimized-in-asp-net-internet-project) post in stackoverflow but that didn't work either.

This is exactly what i receive as error: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the solution of the problem because i am still getting the same error in server explorer, but you can view the table diagram in server object explorer instead.
Also you can view it in SSMS by connecting to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, which is default connection in appconfig or webconfig, or you can change the connection to (localdb)\v11 or (localdb)\ProjectsV12 and again view it either in Server Object Explorer or SSMS. You can see the list of local dbs in command prompt by "sqllocaldb info" command. 
I also found these links pretty useful related to this topic and db connections in code first approach:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidobando/archive/2012/08/14/changing-ef-s-default-provider-from-localdb-to-sql-server.aspx

[How to connect to local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

[Code-First change data source without connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315048/code-first-change-data-source-without-connection-string)
[image]